# My ng-change is not firing on my Angular/Rails app

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, angularjs

I am building a notecard application and for some reason my ng-change is not firing at all. I cannot figure out what the issue is. I tried breakpoints in the JS to verify that it is not actually firing. I'm positive it's got to be a something small I missed. I just need a second pair of eyes on it.

Here is the `JS`

```
var app = angular.module('catalyst', ['faye']);

app.factory('Faye', [
  '$faye', function($faye) {
    return $faye("http://localhost:9292/faye");
  }
]);

app.directive('stickyNote', function(Faye) {
  var linker = function(scope, element, attrs) {
      element.draggable({
        stop: function(event, ui) {
          Faye.publish('/ui/board', {
            id: scope.note.id,
            x: ui.position.left,
            y: ui.position.top
          });
        }
      });

      Faye.subscribe('/ui/board', function(data) {
        // Update if the same note
        if(data.id == scope.note.id) {
          element.animate({
            left: data.x,
            top: data.y
          });
        }
      });

      // Some DOM initiation to make it nice
      element.css('left', '10px');
      element.css('top', '50px');
      element.hide().fadeIn();
    };

  var controller = function($scope) {
      // Incoming
      Faye.subscribe('/ui/board', function(data) {
        // Update if the same note
        if(data.id == $scope.note.id) {
          $scope.note.title = data.title;
          $scope.note.body = data.body;
        }       
      });

      // Outgoing
      $scope.updateNote = function(note) {
        Faye.publish('/ui/board', note);
      };

      $scope.deleteNote = function(id) {
        $scope.ondelete({
          id: id
        });
      };
    };

  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: linker,
    controller: controller,
    scope: {
      note: '=',
      ondelete: '&'
    }
  };
});

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, Faye) {
  $scope.notes = [];

  // Incoming
  Faye.subscribe('/ui/board', function(data) {
    $scope.notes.push(data);
  });

  Faye.subscribe('/ui/board', function(data) {
    $scope.handleDeletedNoted(data.id);
  });

  // Outgoing
  $scope.createNote = function() {
    var note = {
      id: new Date().getTime(),
      title: 'New Note',
      body: 'Pending'
    };

    $scope.notes.push(note);
    Faye.publish('/ui/board', note);
  };

  $scope.deleteNote = function(id) {
    $scope.handleDeletedNoted(id);

    Faye.publish('/ui/board', {id: id});
  };

  $scope.handleDeletedNoted = function(id) {
    var oldNotes = $scope.notes,
    newNotes = [];

    angular.forEach(oldNotes, function(note) {
      if(note.id != id) newNotes.push(note);
    });

    $scope.notes = newNotes;
  }
});
```

Here is the `ui/board.html.haml`

```
%body{"ng-controller" => "MainCtrl"}
  %nav.top-bar{"data-topbar" => ""}
    %ul.title-area
      %li.name
        %h1
          %a{:href => "#"} AngularJS CollabBoard
      %li.toggle-topbar.menu-icon
        %a{:href => "#"}
          %span Menu
    %section.top-bar-section  
      %ul.right
        %li
          %a#createButton{"ng-click" => "createNote()"} Create Note
  .alert-box.success.radius.sticky-note{"ng-repeat" => "note in notes track by $index", :note => "note", :ondelete => "deleteNote(id)", "sticky-note" => ""}
    %button.close{"ng-click" => "deleteNote(note.id)", :type => "button"} &times;
    %input.title{"ng-change" => "updateNote(note)", "ng-model" => "note.title", :type => "text"}
      %textarea.body{"ng-change" => "updateNote(note)", "ng-model" => "note.body"} {{note.body}}
```

Comment: Isn't it because you didn't put the controller code inside your actual controller `MainCtrl` ? Or is it intended to have it in the directive ? If `deleteNote` works, but not `updateNote`, that's probably where it's coming from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a lot to look at here, I believe you have scoping issue. For one, you are not using transclude on your directive and therefore your child elements would not be included in your compiled directive. I noticed also that you have deleteNote on your main controller and are delegating upwords to the maincontroller but then put updateNote on just the directive. I imagine your delete is working. You are using ng-repeat which does create a child scope for each "note".

Comment: Ah, ok thank you! I think you might be right. I haven't used ng-transclude before either. This is my second Angular app. My delete is kinda working. It's deleting the element and then rebuilding the element without the default text. It's really strange, but I think this just tells me I need to go back to my tutorials. Thanks for your help. I feel scoping is the issue.

Comment: @TaylorMitchell, transclude:true is used when you want the directive to contain arbitrary stuff - that arbitrary stuff has the ng-transclude directive. There are examples out there, glad I could help